# using ExpandoMetaclass in groovy print result and null value also

Tags: groovy, expandometaclass

the sample progame when i try to run using the expandometaclass technique it give me two output one the desired result second one "null" as output, from where null is picked up ?

```
class testA {

    static  def X(def var) {
        Y(var)
    }

    static def Y(def var) {
        println var
    }
}
testA.metaClass.static.newMethod = {z_var -> X(z_var) }
println testA.newMethod("anish")
```

output:

```
anish
**null**
```

why this progranme also print null as output

Comment: You should try to follow [naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) when writing classes and methods.  Classes normally start with a capital letter, and methods start with a lowercase letter, so your class would be better named `TestA` and your methods `x` and `y` respectively.  This will have the benefit of making your code easier to read by other people

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for the suggestion i will do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `null` is the return value from `newMethod`. In case you don't want this to be printed remove the `println` from your line

```
println testA.newMethod("anish")
```